# get "Undefined symbols for architecture i386:" trying to get constants

Tags: ios

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, bit I didn't find my case:

I have:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BSConstants : NSObject

extern NSString* const DB_COLUMN_NAME;
extern NSString* const DB_COLUMN_PRICE;
extern NSString* const DB_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION;
extern NSString* const DB_COLUMN_ICON;     
extern NSString* const DB_COLUMN_IMAGE; 

@end

#import "BSConstants.h"

@implementation BSConstants

NSString* const DB_COLUMN_NAME              = @"name";
NSString* const DB_COLUMN_PRICE             = @"price";
NSString* const DB_COLUMN_DESCRIPTION       = @"description";
NSString* const DB_COLUMN_ICON              = @"icon";
NSString* const DB_COLUMN_IMAGE             = @"image";

@end
```

and I when I try to build my project - I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_CONST_SHOPPING_CART_PURCHASE_MAX_SIZE", referenced from:
      -[BSShoppingCartViewController onBuyButtonPressed:] in BSShoppingCartViewController.o
  "_NAME_CREATED_FILE", referenced from:
      -[BSImageSaver saveImageAsPng:] in BSImageSaver.o
  "_NAME_DOWNLOADS_FOLDER", referenced from:
      -[BSImageSaver saveImageAsPng:] in BSImageSaver.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**TRY TO ACCESS:**

```
#import "BSConstants.h"

 ... DB_COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: How are you trying to access these constants?

Comment: I found the error - I have diffenrent constant names in .h and .m files. Thanks for all.

Comment: If you found the problem, please post it as the answer and check it. The answer that is already checked is not correct.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've followed your advice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found the error - I have diffenrent constant names in .h and .m files.

Comment: I had the exact same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try change this

`extern NSString* const DB_COLUMN_NAME;` to `extern  const NSString* DB_COLUMN_NAME;`

same with

```
NSString* const DB_COLUMN_NAME              = @"name";
```

to

> const NSString*  DB_COLUMN_NAME              = @"name";

Also see how you access these.

Comment: I found the error - I had different constants names in .h and .m files. Thanks for all.

Comment: BSConstants.m should be added to your application's target so that it can be linked.

Comment: This is crap. Changing from `NSString *const` to `const NSString *` creates a constant `NSString` (witch is immutable by definition), you wouldn't want to do that. This is most definitely not the problem, this creates more problems to the code.